# Закрытие диалогового окна по условию

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть кнопка ОК для некоторого диалогового окна (свойства у нее соответствующие - `DialogResult` == `ОК` и `AcceptButton`). В обработчике нажатия проверяются некоторые условия, и если они не выполняются - вызывается `MessageBox` и по идее управление возвращается к первому окну. Но оно по понятным причинам закрывается - оно же `AcceptButton`. Так вот, как в случае невыполнения условии оставить окно на месте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы всё равно пишете обработчик события нажатия, то уберите значение из свойства `DialogResult` у кнопки и вручную выставляйте свойство формы, если вы хотите её закрыть.

Comment: То есть DialogResult уже предопределяет исход нажатия? Чтобы отдельный обработчик для кнопки не писать? Оки, спасибо